Empty User claims despite the jwt's payload contains the correct claims
As the title says, i'm still a newbie to asp.net so bear with me. I've been trying to implement jwt authentication but stuck on this issue for quite some time now and it's bothering me to no end. The idea is that i got a jwt and i want to extract the user's claims from it, issue is they are always empty. Below is the method i'm using to extract the claims, please do let me know if further information is required :
[HttpGet("UserInfo")]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult<UserAccount> GetCurrentUser()
{   
try
{
    var headers = Request.Headers;
    var authHeader = headers["Authorization"].ToString();

    var token = authHeader.StartsWith("Bearer ") ? authHeader.Substring(7) : authHeader;

    Console.WriteLine(token); // this shows the correct token which correctly contains the claims
    var identity = _http.HttpContext.User;
    if(identity != null)
    {
        var userClaims = identity.Claims;
        Console.WriteLine(userClaims.Count()); // this always outputs 0
        var userName = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(userClaim => userClaim.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;

        return Ok(new
        {
            UserName = userName
        });
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    return BadRequest(e.Message);
}
}

I tried putting the token on jwt.io and everything seemed to be in place and i'm honestly not sure what else i can do.

The Authorization flow should be implemented as below :

Extract authorization token from request.
Validate that token by validation parameters & get claims.
Set extracted claims in HttpContext.

var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = issuer,
                    ValidAudience = audience,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(signingKey))
                };

ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = _tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

context.HttpContext.User = claimsPrincipal;


here, _tokenHandler is a object of JwtSecurityTokenHandler.
You can get claims whenever you want
var principal = httpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
var userIdClaim = principal.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "jwt_userId");

here, jwt_userId is claimId & value is userIdClaim.value .

Thank you for your help, i actually ended up using the JwtSecurityTokenHandler like so:
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var headers = Request.Headers;
var authHeader = headers["Authorization"].ToString();
var token = handler.ReadToken(authHeader.StartsWith("Bearer ") ? authHeader.Substring(7) : authHeader);
it works well for the purposes of the application i'm working on.
Thank you once more for the help.
